# go mongodb find returns "cursor should be an embedded document but is of BSON type invalid"

Tags: mongodb, go

I am getting this error when I make a find to mongodb in Go:

```
ctx, cancel := store.GetCtx()
defer cancel()
collection := store.GetConn().Collection("collection")
cursor := collection.FindOne(
    ctx,
    bson.M{},
)

// This error is: cursor should be an embedded document but is of BSON type invalid
if cursor.Err() != nil {
    fmt.Println(cursor.Err().Error()) 
    return
}
```

Google only gave me this result:

[mongodb issue tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1114)

I'm inside a VPN and the connection string is like this: `mongodb://<IP>:<PORT>/<cluster_name>`, the connection is ok, I tested with `client.Ping()`.

I also checked the collection via the web interface, it is valid and contains documents.

So, I'm stuck. I appreciate help here. Thank you.

Comment: Which mongo package are you using? `FindOne()` does not return a cursor; it returns a `*SingleResult` which you then use the `Decode(v interface{})` method on. Also, the filter for `FindOne()` should be `bson.D{}`, for instance: `bson.D{{Key: "id", Value: userID}}`. If you want a cursor then use the `Find()` method instead of `FindOne()`. See [this documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo)

Comment: Yes @PatrickMahomes it worked! It was the bson.M as you mentioned. I was using the same version of your link, and the cursor was just a bad name for the variable, it was a *SigleResult. I've changed it in the real code. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, the error returned. It is network related. I changed the connection string to a complete one, to match with the mongo compass uses and it worked.